# Including FUSE sshFS functionality in my PyQt app

Tags: python, ssh, pyqt, macfuse

I am writing an application that wants to mount a remote file system over SSH.  Instead of writing a custom SSH browser, I am tempted to -somehow- bundle MacFUSE (or something) with the application.  Then my application could just use the bundled MacFUSE to mount the remote file system over SSH and open a Finder window for the operator.

For instance, my application ships with a compiled rsync binary.  I wonder if I can compile a MacFUSE binary, tuck it into my application's bundle, and use it for mounting the remote file system?  Or does MacFUSE need a more involved (and perhaps privileged) installation procedure?

What's the best way to go with this?  Should I write my own SSH browser?